# I want to update multiple rows in a table but iff the value of a certain column does not exist in a different table?

Tags: t-sql, where-clause

This select query give me the columns I want to modify

```
Select * From Location 
where Location.DeviceAddress not in (Select DeviceAddress From Device)  order by DeviceAddress desc
```

However, this update query

```
Update Location 
set DeviceAddress = NULL
where Location.DeviceAddress not in (Select DeviceAddress From Device)
```

Gives me the following error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

For reference I am using Microsoft Server 2008 , and, as always, assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this error was being caused by a query in an update trigger on the Location table so I was able to solve it by disabling (and after some time fixing) the trigger. Thank you to all who took the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try

```
 Update Location set DeviceAddress = NULL where Location.DeviceAddress not in (Select 
 top 1 DeviceAddress From Device where Device.DeviceAddress == Location.DeviceAddress)
```

in this case your subquery will return only 1 value instead of multiple.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Update 
  Location 
set 
  DeviceAddress = NULL
where 
  not exists (Select null From Device where Device.DeviceAddress = Location.DeviceAddress)
```